# Python - manipulate list only if its length is greater than X

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, content-length

For a small test I am doing, I need to print the 5th element of a list, if there is one.

```
with open (my_file, 'r') as my_probe:
    for fileLine in my_probe:
        src_string = fileLine.split()
        my_list = list(src_string) # The list may contain any number of items
        if len(my_list) > 3: # Only if lists is longer than 4 items
            print("Info I need: "+my_list[4])
```

When I run the code, however, it nevertheless tries to print the 5th element of lists with less then 5 elements and thus returns an error showing I am trying to print unexisting item:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 70, in <module>
    print ("Info I need: "+my_list[4])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could anyone suggests a way to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `my_list[4]` is the fifth element of `my_list`. Python indices start from `0`. Also `len(my_list) > 3:` does not mean `# Only if lists is longer than 4 items`, it means `# Only if lists is longer than 3 items`.

Comment: Use a try/except?

Comment: If you want to print the 5th element, the length of the list has to be greater than 4, not 3...

Comment: I am not certain how to go about the the try / except approach but changing the if condition solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open (my_file) as my_probe:
    for fileLine in my_probe:
        src_string = fileLine.split()
        my_list = list(src_string) # The list may contain any number of items
        if len(my_list) >= 5: # Only if lists is longer than 4 items
            print("Info I need: "+my_list[4])
```

Note down the list index starts with `0` however `length` is the count of actual element in that list.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, in deed, it's been a brain freeze from my end. It would make absolutely no sense to say a list with 1 item has length of 0 despite the first item being counted as position 0 (my_list[0]), as this puts the question what would be given as length for lists with no items. I spent so much time trying to figure out what I am doing wrong and it was the most obvious thing!

Answer (score 0):

First one there is no string named `my_string` in your code. Other Problem is you are accessing the `5th` element of list which has length of 3. so you have change your if statement to `if len(my_list)>=5`.

```
 with open (my_file, 'r') as my_probe:
    for fileLine in my_probe:
        src_string = fileLine.split()
        my_list = list(src_string) # The list may contain any number of items
        if len(my_list) >= 5: # Only if lists is longer than 4 items
            print(my_list[4])
```

Comment: This solved it, yes, thank you. It appears I got the idea wrong - counting starts at 0 but length at 1 when there are any items in the list.

Comment: This checks if the length of the list is 6 or more, not 5